# Двумерный массив(треуг матрица)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void fill_matrix(int **a, int N);
void print_matrix(int **a, int N);

int main(void)
{
    int N;
    int i;
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    int **A = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    }
    fill_matrix(A, N);
    print_matrix(A, N);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void fill_matrix(int **a, int N) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            //scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]);
        a[i][j] = (i <= j) ? i * N + j + 1 : 0;
}

void print_matrix(int **a, int N) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            printf("%4d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы первая строка матрицы заполнялась пользователем(т е ввод с клавиатуры) В каждой следующей строке элемент a[i][j] получен как сумма
 a[i-1][j-1] и a[i-1][j]. i первых элементов каждой строки нули.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
void fill_matrix(int **a, int N) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            scanf_s("%d", &a[0][i]);

    for (i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            a[i][j] = (i > j) ? 0 : a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j];
}
```

Сначала вводим первую строку, потом считаем остальное.